# Will the water be able to drain out of a blocked toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drainage, clog

Our toilet is backed up and water is filled to the brim but there is nothing else in the bowl. I turned off the water supply for the toilet with the little knob connected to the wall, but will the water still be able to drain out of the bowl?

Comment: If you let all the water drain out, you may not be able to loosen the blockage effectively.

Answer (score 3):

Water usually seeps past most blockages, but not always.

You may have to hand bail the bowl down 1/3 or 1/2.  THEN employ a plunger.  The older cup plungers worked best with a strong UP pull (hence the bowl draining).

If its a newer, smaller tank, an older cup plunger may not make a tight fit:

[image]

This style may work better and will both push and pull against the blockage:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one!

[1 gallon vinegar](http://www.fooducate.com/blog/wp-content/media/White-Vinegar.jpg)
[image: Big bottle of vinegar]

My wife tell's it's works!